calculate total power of each user depending on the timestamp and polynomial function
There're lots of users who use my software to provide whatever number(denoted as variable k) they want alongside with a startTimestamp number. Then I have a function that provides what the power of that user is at specific time t.
Function is as such:
$y(t) = k(\frac{1}{7}t^2 + \frac{2}{7}t + 1)$ (where k is that user's provided number and t = t' - startTimestamp)
So for example: Assume that Alice provided k = 15 and startTimestamp = 1726145353(which is exactly now - Thursday, 12 September 2024 12:49:13). Then if we want to calculate how much power Alice has at timestamp = 1826145353, we will do as such:
$y(1826145353) = 15(\frac{1}{7}(1826145353 - 1726145353)^2 + \frac{2}{7}(1826145353 - 1726145353) + 1)$
Basically, t is substituted as how much time has passed between the startTimestamp and the timestamp at which we want to know user's power.
Each user provides k and startTimestamp as they wish.

Now, I need to be able to calculate the total power of all users at a specific time. Total power is definitelly all user's power summed up at specific time. Let's say we want to calculate total power at timestamp = 300000000. So what we would do is:

get user1's k-of-user1 and startTimestamp_of_user1.
get user2's k-of-user2 and startTimestamp_of_user2.
get user3's k-of-user3 and startTimestamp_of_user3.

Once we get all users's numbers, we do:
$y(300000000) = \text{k-of-user1}(\frac{1}{7}(300000000 - \text{startTimestamp_of_user1})^2 + \frac{2}{7}(300000000 - \text{startTimestamp_of_user1}) + 1) + \text{k-of-user2}(\frac{1}{7}(300000000 - 
\text{startTimestamp_of_user2})^2 + \frac{2}{7}(300000000 - \text{startTimestamp_of_user2}) + 1) + ...$
In theory, this seems easy but I am working in a programming language where looping through all users is not an option for me as looping costs too much and if users are too many, it won't even let me loop through all of them. So I need somehow a way that each time each user provides k and startTimestamp, I would update some kind of global curve that I can come up with. This way, looping wouldn't be needed as each time I wanna figure out total power, I'd substitute t in this new curve function that is of total power curve.
Is there a way mathematically such that each time new k and startTimestamp is inserted, I can somehow track of what new total power curve formula function should be ? As interesting as it might be, I heard that if the y(t) function had been as linear, this problem is solved with slopeChanges, but here I hit the dead end.

It is unlikely for such a formula to exist, especially because we don't know what pattern your startTimestamp and k follow. Maybe try seeing the pattern of coefficients of $y(t)$ as k and startTimestamp of more and more users are added and add that to the post. That way if they do follow a sequence we can figure out a formula for that. One more thing - it might be better to see if there's some programming optimisation you could do to be still able to follow a loop-like strategy.

@Kraken no chance for optimization of loop-like. I am using blockchain solidity language, so no chance for that. k is always an integer > 0 and startTimestamp is epoch time timestamp in seconds.

Hmm...here's your total power function a bit more mathematically: $$ Y_j(t) = \frac{t^2 + 2t + 7}{7} \sum_{i=1}^{j} k_i  - \frac{2(t+1)}{7} \sum_{i=1}^{j} k_i T_i + \sum_{i=1}^{j} k_i {T_i}^2$$ where $Y_j(t)$ is the total power for $j$ users, $k_i$ is the k of the $i$th user and $T_i$ is the startTimestamp of the $i$th user.

That's fine but this still requires to know each user's startTimestamp and k at the time of figuring out the total power which would need a loop

Not exactly? I am not much of a programmer but you could save the $j-1$th state and then find the $j$th state by simply adding $\frac{k_j(t^2+2t-7)}{7} - \frac{2(t+1)k_j T_j}{7} + k_j {T_j}^2$, and you can get these values by slicing the $-1$th element of a list/database/whatever way you're procuring k and startTimestamp
